# GCP logging throwing an error when submitting more that 1 log per seco

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, logging

I am trying to implement logging in Flask. The API run on Google App Engine and I am using GCP Logging. It works, unless I submit more that around 1 log per second. I have the permission to create logs since some of them are recorded without any issues and some of them aren't.

The Python code is:

```
...
import logging
import google.cloud.logging

...
@app.route("/log", methods=['GET'])
    def log():
        logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.INFO,
        )
        logging.info('Hello')

        client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
        client.get_default_handler()
        client.setup_logging()

        return 'info log'
```

The error:

`` `Failed to submit 1 logs.` ``

Traceback:

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
details = "Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 114, in _safely_commit_batch
    batch.commit()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/logger.py", line 453, in commit
    client.logging_api.write_entries(entries, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py", line 160, in write_entries
    self._gapic_api.write_log_entries(request=request)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/logging_service_v2/client.py", line 631, in write_log_entries
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
domain: "iam.googleapis.com"
```

I followed Google tutorial https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python and I didn't have any issues locally with Pythons logging library. I tried rewriting code to instantiate the handler only once from a Python module but then I was getting this error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED`, in this case, means that the principal performing the action is lacking the `logging.logEntries.create` permission. This permission is included in the [**Logs Writer**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#logging.logWriter) predefined role.

Reading through the [article](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python) you shared, looks like if you would like to [run your application locally and elsewhere](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#run-local), you need to first:

- Grant the service account the Logs Writer IAM role.
- Set up [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-key).

If this is not the case, then check that the underlying service account has the Logs Writer role. Hope it helped! :)

Comment: Thank you, I gave those permissions to the wrong service account before. If anyone else is struggling in the future look what account did you generate a key for.